# UPDATE using prepared statements gives unexpected T_VARIABLE error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog set entrytitle = ?,blogentry = ? where id = ?')
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $entrytitle,$blogentry,$id);
```

The error is from the second line but I get the feeling it's being caused by the UPDATE query.

DB columns for the items are:

entrytitle is varchar(65)
blogentry is longtext
id is int(11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a semi-colon on line 1...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog set entrytitle = ?,blogentry = ? where id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $entrytitle,$blogentry,$id);
```

Now the second `$stmt` is **unexpected**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing semicolon, replace

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog set entrytitle = ?,blogentry = ? where id = ?') // <-- missing semicolon here!
```

with

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog set entrytitle = ?,blogentry = ? where id = ?'); // <-- now fixed
```

but let me say, this is simple standard debugging...

Comment: Right! Fixed, thanks.

Comment: :)  I knew it was something simple. THanks folks!

Comment: You're welcome :) If the answer helped you, feel free to upvote and/or accept it!

Comment: I can't upvote/accept. I think I'm too much of a noob... :/ (I have negative 3 for my question) maybe it was formatted poorly?

Comment: @user3115806 - you should be able to accept after (I think) 15 minutes have passed; you can't upvote until you have 15 reputation.